# safe1 cannot be resolved (JUnit)

Tags: java, junit

Only just started with JUnit but I can't help this error, here's the code snippet:

```
package ss.week2.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import ss.week2.hotel.Safe;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SafeTest {

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Safe safe1 = new Safe();
    Safe safe2 = new Safe();
    safe2.activate("Initial");
}

@Test
public void testSetToActiveWrong() {
    System.out.println("Testing setting to active with wrong password: ");
    assertEquals("safe1.activate(\"wrongwrong\")", true, safe1.activate("wrongwrong"));
    assertEquals("safe2.activate(\"wrongwrong\")", false, safe2.activate("wrongwrong"));
}

// Some other tests

public void runTests() {
    setUp();
    testSetToActiveWrong();
    setUp();
    testOpenWrong();
    setUp();
    testOpenRight();
    setUp();
    testDeactivate();
}

private void assertEquals(String text, boolean expected, boolean result) {
        System.out.println("        " + text);
        System.out.println("            Expected:  " + expected);
        System.out.println("            Result: " + result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Initial conditions: ");
    System.out.println("safe1 is closed and not active.");
    System.out.println("safe2 is closed but active.");
    new SafeTest().runTests();
}
}
```

calling assertEquals gives me the error: safe1 cannot be resolved
why is this? I think I have initialized the variable (without errors), I have imported the package and file in which the file to be tested is (note: Safe.java is in another package).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you see a variable safe1 defined in the method or in the class where it's used? I can't. Methods can't access local variables of other methods.

Comment: A Junit class is a class, decorated with snails. The same rules apply. Use fields to communicate between methods.

Comment: So I now declared it in the main class (before settUp()) and initialized them in the class setUp(), it gives me no errors, is this the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`safe1` is declared as a local variable in your `setUp()` function. If you want it accessible from other methods, it should be declared as a data memeber:

```
public class SafeTest {

    Safe safe1;
    Safe safe2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        safe1 = new Safe();
        safe2 = new Safe();
        safe2.activate("Initial");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetToActiveWrong() {
        System.out.println("Testing setting to active with wrong password: ");
        assertEquals("safe1.activate(\"wrongwrong\")", true, safe1.activate("wrongwrong"));
        assertEquals("safe2.activate(\"wrongwrong\")", false, safe2.activate("wrongwrong"));
    }

    // rest of class...
```